# Second element's value is the same as the first element after I incremented the address by 1?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int main() {

    string bucky[2];

    bucky[0] = "hello";
    bucky[1] = "world";

    string *bp0 = &bucky[0];
    string *bp1 = &bucky[1];

    cout << "bp0 is at " << bp0 << " element is " << *bp0 << endl;
    cout << "bp1 is at " << bp1 << " element is " << *bp1 << endl;

    bp0++;

    cout << "bp0 is now at " << bp0 << " element is " << *bp0 << endl;
    cout << "bp1 is now at " << bp1 << " element is " << *bp1 << endl;
}
```

The last two lines shows that element 1 and element 2 now shares the same value, and the same address? Am I understanding this correctly? Plus, what happens to the address of the first element after I incremented it by one?

Answer (score 1):

> The last two lines shows that element 1 and element 2 now shares the same value, and the same address?

`bp0` and `bp1` point to the same place in memory, so the pointers have the same value. Obviously, the thing they point to must also be the same, because there is only one place in memory with the given address.

> what happens to the address of the first element after I incremented it by one?

You are incrementing a pointer to the first element by one. When you do that, you get the address of the second element. Pointer arithmetic is set up like that: when you point to index `x` into an array and add an integer number `y` to the pointer, you end up with a pointer to element `x+y`.

This works for both positive and negative `y`, as long as `x+y` is non-negative, and below the number of elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the command `string *bp0 = &bucky[0];`, you have done two things:

1.Get the address of `bucky[0]`, then return the address to the pointer `bp0`;

2.Assign the value of `bucky[0]` (here is "hello") to `*bp0`.

After `bp0++`, the address of `bp0` moves to the next place. Here the array is stored continuously, so `bucky[1]` is the next one.  That's the reasons why element 1 and element 2 now shares the same value, and the same address.

The address and value of `bucky[0]` are not changed, you can print out them like this: `cout << &bucky[0] << " " << bucky[0] << endl;`.

What's more, it's unpredictable and dangerous, if you use `bp0++` in the case that bp0 does not point to an array variable or `++` will out the index range of the array.